# is it possible to mask a letter as whitespace in HTML? In this case I would like to mask UNDERSCORE(_) as a whitespace

Tags: html

is it possible to mask a letter as whitespace in HTML? In this case I would like to  mask UNDERSCORE(_) as a whitespace

```
           <input type="text" value=I_NEED_TO_HIDE_UNDERSCORE>
```

Comment: Do you mean `value="I NEED TO HIDE UNDERSCORE"`?

Comment: yes! That is what I mean excaclty

Comment: Maybe use [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event to read the value and then [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) all underscores with " "

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event to listen for alterations to the input value and then the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace your desired letter with a blank space.

However, note that with `<input type="text"` elements, "the change event doesn't fire until the control loses focus" – [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). In other words, this usually means that you have to 'click away' from the input field before the event fires.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

// add event listener
input.addEventListener('change', updateInput);

function updateInput() {
  // replace set letter (in this case underscore) with blank space
  input.value = input.value.replace("_", " ");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
```

If you want the input value to be updated straight away (as the value of the `<input>` element changes), you can use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event instead:

```js
...

// add event listener
input.addEventListener('input', updateInput);

...
```